# Is there any way to get colored html entities...?

Tags: html, css

Here I want html entities in colors. As the default color is black, I want them to be in specific color without css styling. Is that possible....

```css
    .error_number {
      color: #F00;
    }
```

```html
<span class="error_number">&#10004;</span>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you need css styling for html elements, you can do that via the html though if you do not want a style sheet so to speak

Comment: I am verifying my site in ios device where it is not displaying colors which I specified

Comment: @Niveditha: How did you specify colors? Please show the code.

Comment: I added the code. This is working in desktop browsers, but not in ios.

Comment: You can't color characters without CSS, unless the font already has the colors by default. You could create your own font with a tool like [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io)

Comment: Well, emojis are colored... ✅☑️

Answer (score 16):

No. HTML entities represent characters. Characters (except for emoji) do not have inherent colour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  This should work.

```
<span style="color:F00;" class="error_number">&#10004;</span>
```

Since you don't want to change the color in the style tags.

Comment: this is not an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use the in-line `style` option:

```
<span class="error_number" style="color:f00;">&#10004;</span>
```

CSS can easily be implemented inline with the `style` element. Though, it isn't recommended for larger jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to use css "filter" property.

```css
// this converts black to green
     filter: invert(26%) sepia(76%) saturate(1788%) hue-rotate(95deg) brightness(92%) contrast(101%);
```

Here's a codepen I found to calculate filter for target colour.

> https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp